# cache react component on router change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have timer component which should keep running even when the react-router routes `/settings` but it re-renders which leads to the loss of state.

Timer.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { CircularProgressbarWithChildren } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
import { BsPlayFill, BsPauseFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { convertToMin } from 'renderer/utils/time';

const Timer = () => {
  const config = useSelector((state) => state.timer);
  const defaultSeconds = config.workTime;
  const defaultBreakSeconds = config.breakTime;
  const [time, setTime] = useState({});
  const timer = useRef(0);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('focus');
  const seconds = useRef(defaultSeconds);

  function countDown() {
    seconds.current--;
    setTime(convertToMin(seconds.current));

    if (seconds.current <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
      restartTimer();
    }
  }
  function restartTimer() {
    if (mode === 'focus') {
      var sec = defaultBreakSeconds;
      setMode('break');
    } else {
      var sec = defaultSeconds;
      setMode('focus');
    }

    timer.current = 0;
    seconds.current = sec;
    setTime(convertToMin(sec));
    setPaused(true);
  }
  function startTimer() {
    if (seconds.current > 0 && timer.current === 0) {
      timer.current = setInterval(() => countDown(), 1000);
      setPaused(false);
    }
  }

  function getProgress(sec) {
    return Math.floor((seconds.current / sec) * 100);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    timer.current = 0;
    setPaused(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let t = convertToMin(defaultSeconds);

    setTime(t);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="timer-container">
      <div className="progressbar">
        <CircularProgressbarWithChildren
          value={
            mode === 'focus'
              ? getProgress(defaultSeconds)
              : getProgress(defaultBreakSeconds)
          }
          text={`${time.min}:${time.sec}`}
          styles={{
            trail: { strokeWidth: 1, stroke: '#424656' },
            path: {
              strokeWidth: 4,
              stroke: mode === 'break' ? '#3cc08e' : '#00aefc',
            },

            text: {
              fill: '#00aefc',
            },
          }}
        >
          <div className="progress-text">{mode}</div>
        </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
      </div>

      <div className="action-buttons">
        <button type="button">
          {paused ? (
            <BsPlayFill color="#f0fbff" size={30} onClick={startTimer} />
          ) : (
            <BsPauseFill color="#f0fbff" size={30} onClick={pauseTimer} />
          )}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

App.tsx

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/settings" element={<Menu />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

is it possible to cache the component the background, so the state persists and the interval continues?

Comment: Cache the component, no. Cache the state though? Yes. Move the component state that needs to persist into the redux store so when the component mounts it can pick up where it needs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the `Timer` in a separated component, what about move it to outside of the routes definition? that way the component won't be unmounted when you switch routes.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Timer />
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/settings" element={<Menu />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

[here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/timer-not-losing-state-ep4urs) also a sandbox using part of your code.

If you can't do that because of a UI constraint, using `redux` probably solve your issue, or else, you can always make use of [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to manage the state in a higher level